# Updating doc in Pouch DB

Tags: javascript

I have a DB in PouchDB, and I need to be able to update documents. So when I click "update" in the table I get the data from the fields into a form, then I want to change data in the form and press "Save Updated" button and have the fields updated. Here's what I've tried:

```
function saveUpdated(){
    var vaucherID = window.document.VaucherForm.vaucherID.value;
    var date = window.document.VaucherForm.date.value;
    var invoiceNumber = window.document.VaucherForm.invoiceNumber.value;
    var vendorID = window.document.VaucherForm.vendorID.value;
    var amount = window.document.VaucherForm.amount.value;
    var fund = window.document.VaucherForm.fund.value;
    var deptID = window.document.VaucherForm.deptID.value;
    var descript =  window.document.VaucherForm.descript.value;
     //I get idValue from when I have all values from DB get into form
    db.get('idValue').then(function(doc) {
      return db.put({
        _id: 'idValue',
        _rev: doc._rev,
        vaucherID: vaucherID,
        date: date,
        invoiceNumber: invoiceNumber,
        vendorID: vendorID,
        amount: amount,
        fund: fund,
        deptID: deptID,
        descript: descript
      });
    }).then(function(response) {
      // handle response
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

So as I do this I get this error

```
o {status: 404, name: "not_found", message: "missing", error: true, reason: "missing"}
```

Comment: looks more like a configuration or setup issue than anything to do with the code you posted. Show us how you're initialising the db.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, maybe it's because the `doc._rev` is undefined/null, so this is treated differently than just not including the `_rev` field at all? Do you have a live example to reproduce?